# C cross-platform RPC that requires minimal boilerplate?

Tags: c, linux, windows, rpc

I have an existing library in C, which I want to be able to allow remote access to (either from Linux or Windows).

I looked at the usual RPC suspects like Thrift and Protobuf, but neither of these deal cleanly with C-style function calls (things like pass-by-ref, char* instead of string, * instead of List<> etc).

In short, to use either of these it looks like I would need to write a complete IDL from scratch, and add a lot of boilerplate code to transfer C-style function calls into these environments.

Are there any RPC libraries around that

- can deal directly with C header files (or have tools to auto
  generate the initial IDL from C definitions)?
- are cross-platform Linux/Windows compatible?
- require the absolute minimum of boilerplate code?
- support sockets
- are relatively high performance (XML-RPC i'm looking at you)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's [protobuf-c](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c), an implementation of protobuf in C.

And then there's the classical [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), found on most/(all?) unix-like systems, versions exist for windows as well. See also the [Linux xdr(3) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/xdr.3.html) which contains an overview of the API.

Note that both protobuf and XDR are serialization libraries, they don't provide RPC. The "companion RPC library" to XDR is called, well, [RPC](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rpc.3.html), but I don't think anyone writes new code with that, and AFAICS it's unix-specific (portmap doesn't run on windows, does it? And it's generally a bad idea anyway.). Then there's [protobuf-c-rpc](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c-rpc) which is the C version of the protobuf RPC library; probably a better bet than classic RPC.